# Ссылка в браузере

Tags: java

У меня есть сервер с сайтом с портом `80`, как мне сделать что бы к нему можно было подключиться в браузере через ссылку а не через `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Вы не понимаете принципов работы сети, мне кажется. Вам необходимо купить или получить доменное имя, которое будет ссылаться на ваш сервер. Также, на машине с сервером должен быть открыт порт.

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев я делаю на локальном

Comment: Подключится по ссылке из интернета или с локальной машины? ip адрес внешний статический или динамический? Операционная система на сервере какая?

Comment: @AndrewHobbit это не сервер, я делаю на своём ПК. ip статический. Подключиться через браузер Google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если хотите подключиться по ссылке с локальной машины, то добавьте в файл `/etc/hosts` запись `127.0.0.1 example.com` и подключайтесь к example.com в браузере. Если подключаться с другой машины, но в локальной сети, то добавьте в её `hosts` запись `внутренний ip адрес машины с сайтом example.com`. Ну а если хотите из интернета подключаться, то надо зарегистрировать доменное имя и привязать к нему Ваш статический внешний ip адрес. Или воспользоваться, например, каким-нибудь сервисом типа [noip.com](http://noip.com) или [dynip.com](http://dynip.com)